# Under what conditions would deleted files restore themselves?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, trash

Just to be clear I'm not looking for how to restore deleted files.

Using Arch (5.16.8-arch1-1) and KDE (Plasma 5.24.0).

I just went to check my Trash folder to restore something, only to find out that it's filled with files some of which were deleted at least 2 weeks ago. But not only I emptied the Trash folder several times, I have reinstalled the whole system twice in last 2 days, [supposedly?] erasing the whole disk with the previous installation.

The installations were made with [Arch Linux GUI](https://sourceforge.net/projects/arch-linux-gui/) with the option to Erase Disk (maybe not the exact wording). They weren't interrupted mid-way, there's no dualboot and I'm not running any backup services.

At the time of deletion system was EndeavourOS with XFCE.

I'm utterly confused about how is that even possible and couldn't find anything on the topic. Any clues would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Reinstalling Linux only erases the disk if you specifically formatted it at the beginning of the installation.

Comment: @harrymc So the "Erase Disk" option, well, does not erase disk?

Comment: That depends on the installation.

Comment: If you truly erased the disk, then the files were saved elsewhere on your system.

Comment: 99.9% sure files weren't saved anywhere else and 100% sure I chose the option to erase the disk. I'm going to assume that this has something to do with disk not being erased correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found what caused this.

While post mentions that no backup services were running, well actually I used FreeFileSync once, but to backup files *from* this computer *to* flash drive, which I either forgot to mention because [seemingly] nothing was added to the system in question.

So, when mirroring files from PC to flash drive, FFS moved deleted [from PC] files from flash drive to PC's Trash directory according to its default settings. Now on my previous installation this option was turned off and they were deleted permanently, but while I assumed it was off by default, being unsure I still went to check the Trash which was empty. But also KDE doesn't refresh Trash directory automatically (for whatever reason), which I only discovered later, so there were files but they weren't displaying.

Such a trivial cause in retrospect but I was so flabbergasted by 3 month old files chilling in Trash folder when this happened it didn't even cross my mind.